# CRSP Permco Aggregation

Tags: programming, fama-french, crsp

I saw that for one CRSP Permco, there could be multiple CRSP Permnos. Could anybody provide guidance on how to aggregate the market capitalization, returns, etc... by permco and date? I am currently summing the market capitalization by permco and date, and then I keep the permno with the largest market capitalization. However, as a result the number of stocks are a few (1, 2 or 3) more or less than Fama and French. Therefore, I was wondering what the correct way to do this was.

Kind regards,

Guyon

PS: As an example, I have 511 stocks for 1926-06-30 while Fama and French have 510 stocks for 1926-06-30 and as a result my breakpoint is equal to 13.77 instead of 13.6 which slightly skews the results.

Comment: 511 for you and 510 for Fama-French. That is a very close agreement IMO, I am impressed. (I do not think I was able to match this when I was working with CRSP).

Comment: It seems that they construct the CRSP Universe of all stocks in a slightly different way, I can provide code snippets if that helps in giving suggestions.